# How to make `\emph`ed letters bold italic when they are in `\textbf`?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, bold, italic, emphasis

I have some `emph`asised letters in `\textbf{}`, i.e. `\textbf{\emph{abc}}`, to bold-italicise the letters. However, the text merely comes to be italic, not bold italic. How can I redefine `\emph` to get bold italic letters when I have to use `\emph` in `\textbf{}`?

I also have to use `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale = MatchUppercase,BoldFont = Libertinus Sans Bold]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont[Scale = MatchUppercase,BoldFont = LinBiolinum_RB.otf,ItalicFont = LinBiolinum_RI.otf,BoldItalicFont = LinBiolinum_RBO.otf]{LinBiolinum_R.otf}

\begin{document}

I want to make \textbf{\emph{abc}} bold italic,
like 
{\sffamily\bfseries\emph{abc}}.

\end{document}
```

## Output of the MWE in my environment

[image]

Comment: On my system, `abc` *is* shown in bold italic. Do you have Libertinus Serif Bold Italic installed?

Comment: Yes, I have `LinBiolinum_RBO.otf` on my computer. I set `BoldItalicFont = LinBiolinum_RBO.otf` in the MWE, too. However, `\textbf{\emph{abc}}` does not show any bold italic letters, as demonstrated in the edited post.

Comment: The MWE worked fine for me with LuaLaTeX but threw an error with XeLaTeX. I decided to use font names for all `\set...font` invocations and completed the `ItalicFont` and `BoldItalicFont` settings for Libertinus as in https://gist.github.com/moewew/156157c46c07a1b8260f8c3ec0a9ddb0 and now things work fine with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your suggestion. I confirmed that your gist works great! Would you want to post the gist as an answer? I will surely accept and up-vote that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from the question works as-is for me with LuaLaTeX, but throws an error with XeLaTeX (`dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (1)`).

In my experience loading files with file names instead of font names is usually much more reliable.

So if we replicate what you already did for Biolinum in `\setsansfont` also for Libertinus in `\setmainfont` we end up with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Scale = MatchUppercase,
  BoldFont = LibertinusSerif-Bold.otf,
  ItalicFont = LibertinusSerif-Italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = LibertinusSerif-BoldItalic.otf,
]{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}
\setsansfont[
  Scale = MatchUppercase,
  BoldFont = LinBiolinum_RB.otf,
  ItalicFont = LinBiolinum_RI.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = LinBiolinum_RBO.otf,
]{LinBiolinum_R.otf}

\begin{document}

I want to make \textbf{\emph{abc}} \textbf{bold} \textit{italic},
like
{\sffamily\bfseries\emph{abc}}.

\end{document}
```

which works fine with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

[image: I want to make abc bold italic, like abc.]